# Complex Fourier series expansion with minus sign in the exponent

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, exponential-function, fourier-series

What are the expression for complex Fourier series with a minus sign in the exponent? If a function $f(t)$ periodic with period $T=2\pi/\omega$ can be expanded with Fourier series, then is it possible to write the following?

$$f(t)=\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} c_m e^{-im\omega t}\,\,\,,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, m \in \mathbb{N}$$

Where

$$c_m=\frac{1}{T} \int_{0}^{T}f(t) e^{i m \omega t }dt$$

Usually in texts the sign in the exponents are reversed, but are those expression correct?

Comment: This is a nonstandard notation, but the two are equivalent, by transforming $m \rightarrow-m$.

Comment: So, did my answer help at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expressions are correct.

Most textbooks will switch the minus sign for an aesthetical reason.

It's "nicer" to have your function decomposed with respect to the basis $\{f_n(t)\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ where $$f_n(t) = \cos n\omega t + i \sin n\omega t$$ instead of $f_n(t) = \cos n\omega t - i \sin n\omega t$.